# Android Load URL with string from SearchView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, searchview

I have created a WebView app with Android studio but I want to add a search feature to Navigation drawer or if failing that, the Action bar.

I have added:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/Custom_Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To the Action bar through app_bar_main.xml and I see it on the front end but this is where I cant go any further as I am a complete newbie when it comes to apps.

What I want is the string entered into the search box to be loaded with the search URL of my website.

e.g `webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/result/?q=*search_string*");`

I have spent over 5 hours trying to figure this out and researching what to do with no luck. I have found similar questions regarding this without any answers. I hope someone can point me in the right direction if they are not willing to provide the full answer. thanks

Comment: _As the website is for a non profit organisation I would prefer not to spend my own money to get someone to implement this._ So you expect that people here will implement this for you. I'm sorry but SO is not for this, you can try to implement the app yourself and if you have a technical problem people will happily try to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and this was my last resort. I have helped many people myself with PHP issues and wouldn't discourage others from helping like you down voting my post when all I am doing is helping someone else with this project.

Comment: If you tried to figure this for hours why not show the code you tried so people can help you better. I'm sorry but the formula: "I have this and I want that" doesn't work, never works. Anyway good luck with your project, I removed the downvote but in my opinion I think you should show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

After many days of trying to figure this out I have managed to get it working(ish)

to load an URL with the search string you need to do this:

*MainActivity.Java*

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        Intent searchIntent = getIntent();
        String query = searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchIntent.getAction())) {

            mwebView.loadUrl("http://example.co.uk/result/?q="+query);

        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml* (In main activity)

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

That's it, you will now be able to search your webview website.

When I say I have got it working(ish) my `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` events do not work when loading the search URL but works fine on normal `mwebView.loadUrl` links.

my `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` code is:

```
ProgressBar pd = null;
        ImageView iv = null;
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            pd = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 100);
            iv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 100);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
MyWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//URL_Search is a SearchView.

URL_Search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String url) {

                if (url.contains(".com")){
                    url = "https://www." + url + "/";
                    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
                        MyWebView.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                }
                else{

                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Very simplified approach, but works. Worth as an essay.